# Phpmyadmin MySQL Error in Processing Request Error code: 403 Error text: Forbidden

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, centos

[image]

im able to delete the table, but im not able to edit, copy, delete the row in it. not to mention, query language is giving the same error too.

Comment: You should check http daemon error log for details. If you are using httpd, can you share "tail /var/log/httpd/error.log" command output?

Comment: ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 4). Pattern match "(?:\\\\b(?:(?:s(?:elect list because it is not contained in (?:an aggregate function and there is no|either an aggregate function or the) GROUP BY clause|upplied argument is not a valid (?:PostgreSQL result|O(?:racle|DBC)|M(?:S |y)SQL))|S(?:yntax error c ..." at RESPONSE_BODY. [file "/usr/local/apache/modsecurity-crs/base_rules/modsecurity_crs_50_outbound.conf"][line "123"] [id "970003"] [rev "3"] [msg "SQL Information Leakage"] [data "Matched Data: You have an error in your SQL syntax found within RESPONSE_BODY:

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML><html lang='en' dir='ltr'><meta charset=\\x22utf-8\\x22 /><meta name=\\x22robots\\x22 content=\\x22noindex,nofollow\\x22 /><meta http-equiv=\\x22X-UA-Compatible\\x22 content=\\x22IE=Edge\\x22><style>html{display: none;}</style><link rel=\\x22icon\\x22 href=\\x22favicon.ico\\x22 type=\\x22image/x-icon\\x22 /><link rel=\\x22shortcut icon\\x22 href=\\x22favicon.ico\\x22 type=\\x22image/x-icon\\x22 /><link rel=\\x22stylesheet\\x22 type=\\x2..."] [severity "CRIT [hostname "47.88.193.112"] [uri "/phpMyAdmin/server_privileges.php"] [unique_id "V7x@8X8AAAEAACLrT7AAAAAC"]

Comment: I am getting his error but only on one machine (officer) and not on the other (home). My assumption is, it might have something to do with the firewall used in office? Our firewall has some strict rules.

Answer (score 1):

Finally. the answer was mod_security. after disable it everything works smooth.

Answer (score 1):

Yes if you have installed Mod Security its the reason.
Find phpMyAdmin.conf and disable Mod Security in phpMyAdmin and add SecRuleEngine Off.
Consider other way to secure your phpMyAdmin installation.

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
   SecRuleEngine Off
   ....
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was also mod_security. Instead of disabling it altogether, you can just disable the triggering rule. The rule ID is in the error logs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on `nginx` and for me changing to `php7.4-fpm` from `7.0` fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was an expired SSL certificate, combined with using TLSv1 instead of TLSv1.2 and TLSv1.3. I checked the server error logs for more details, the error was there.

Answer (score 0):

In our case it was Cloudflare blocking it. Looking in the `Network` tab showed that the response was *"Please enable cookies (...) Cloudflare"*. Adding a page rule disabling security for the PhpMyAdmin directory fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

If it was as a result of ModSecurity rules, then place at the bottom of REQUEST-900-EXCLUSION-RULES-BEFORE-CRS.conf the following rules:-

```
SecRule REQUEST_FILENAME "@beginsWith /phpmyadminbeginningpathinurl" \
     "id:1004,\
     phase:2,\
     pass,\
     nolog,\
     ctl:ruleRemoveById=951220"

SecRule REQUEST_FILENAME "@beginsWith /phpmyadminbeginningpathinurl" \
     "id:1005,\
     phase:2,\
     pass,\
     nolog,\
     ctl:ruleRemoveById=942140"
```

for ModSecurity 3 this has resolved the issue, and you might need to adjust the syntax for ModSecurity 2. If you had any issues with other rules blocking request, run the following command:-

tail /var/log/httpd/error_log -f | grep 'phpmyadminbeginningpathinurl'

To trace which rule id, that you will find in the debugging error payload, in format similar to "951220". Adjust your stack accordingly if the rule is needed, otherwise disable the troublemaking rule using extra rules from above examples.